# Display coastline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, shapefile, contour

I have a raster converted from shapefile (tool point to raster). Can anybody prompt, how to display coastline?

I can use contours, but are not focused at condition "elevation = 0". Is there any simple way?

[image: screen]

Colors

[image: colors]

Comment: How, exactly, do the colors you display represent values in the raster?

Comment: @whuber I set this classified scheme myself. Added description to question

Comment: Does that legend imply the coastline should be found at all zero values? Although it would seem to, that appears to contradict your statement about the zero elevation contour. How do you reconcile that?

Comment: @whuber I don't mean, that coast line is absolutely "elevation = 0". I wanted to say, that contours are not focused at "elevation is about 0", implying coastline. Really I don't think, that "=0" is possible, obviously there are different changes of elevation, some where neighbours can have 1 and -1, somewhere 10 and -1 and so on

Comment: So what you seem to mean is that the coastline is where zero values *ought* to be, but (due to the discreteness of the representation) it cannot accurately be found by selecting cells with values exactly zero. That's understandable--it's a common problem--but it does not explain why you rule out computing the zero elevation contour.

Comment: @whuber Generally, there is no problem to compute coast line. It is very easy to program. Wa can just take land area(z > 0) and display bound. But I don't know python and want to get solution just with arcmap interface. Also obviouslly, that taking points with z = 0 is very bad result, I even have tried it, it has no sense, as take range [-1;1] and so on. Take bound of zone with z > 0 is really easy and good solution, I just want to know how to display it in arcmap

Comment: I'd try this. Using raster calculator Con("raster">=0,1). Convert output integer raster to polygon.

Comment: How about Contour List http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000tt000000? with only one entry in the contour values (0) that will give you the coastline from the DEM for that vertical datum and not fully contour the entire raster at an interval.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson this is correct answer, thank you very much, you can post it as answer

Comment: In ArcMap you can easily generate the elevation=0 contour in many ways.  What I am struggling with is that you explicitly reject this natural solution in the question, making it unclear what you really are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want a single elevation (or specific elevations) as lines you can use Contour List ([3d analyst](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q900000071000000), [Spatial analyst](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000tt000000)). Unlike Contour ([3d analyst](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q900000021000000), [Spatial analyst](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000ts000000)) which creates contours at a specific interval the contour list tool produces contour [isolines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line) at specific elevation values.. for this example you would supply the value 0 for contour_values:

[image]

Note that both of these tools require either of 3d analyst or Spatial analyst extension for ArcGis. If you don't have access to either of these extensions (or ArcGis) you can use [GDAL_Contour](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_contour.html) to extract the coastline by supplying a ridiculously high interval:

```
gdal_contour -a elev dem.tif contour.shp -i 2147483647.0
```

2147483647.0 is the maximum value for an INT32 - 32bit integer, substitute a value greater than either the maximum value of the raster or the absolute value of the minimum and only the 0 contour will be produced. A specific value can be obtained using `-off value` but the contour will be given elevation of 0.